# Replace appname in user-agent with volley

Tags: android, user-agent, android-volley

How i can change the User-Agent in request header with the app-name in first section of user-agent like this :
`Myappname (Linux; U; Android 4.3; Galaxy Nexus Build/JWR66Y)`

note that i don't want to change other parameters in user-agnet string

i used volley for requests.

any suggestion to do it dynamically?

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do EXACTLY the same thing in my Android app. Namely, modify the User-Agent header but only append/prepend something and leave the "original" content (or most of it).

The problem with @athor answer is that, if look carefully, volley only uses the `userAgent` string when it uses `HttpClientStack`, and that is for devices using Android API Level 8 lower (in other words, in the minority of cases). For API Levels 9 or higher, it uses `HurlStack`, or,  a stack or your own, if you are passing it as parameter for `newRequestQueue`, which in my case, and probably in most cases, is a subclass of `HurlStack`, for example `OkHttpStack`.
These, make no use of the `userAgent` string you see there, and, as far as I know, don't offer a way to set the user agent.

What I ended up doing was, in one of my subclasses of Volley's `Request<T>`, I overrode the `getHeaders` method, and made the necessary adjustment to the User-Agent header. Here's the code snippet that prepends the app's name and version to the original User-Agent header.

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();
    if (headers == null || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
        headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
    if (context != null) {
        StringBuilder label = new StringBuilder();
        label.append(context.getApplicationInfo().loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()));
        label.append("/");
        try {
            PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            label.append(pInfo.versionName);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        }
        label.append(" ");
        label.append(System.getProperty("http.agent"));
        headers.put("User-Agent", label.toString());
    }
    return headers;
}
```

Note that I'm using `System.getProperty("http.agent")` to access the "original" User-Agent header, as I found no other way to that. Of course, you could try to modify this string to remove the `Dalvik/1.6.0` but I don't know if that's 100% safe.
Also, note that I'm using Android `Context` to read app name and version.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Volley sets up the user agent in the newRequestQueue method.

```
 public static RequestQueue newRequestQueue(Context context, HttpStack stack) {
    File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), DEFAULT_CACHE_DIR);

    String userAgent = "volley/0";
    try {
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
        userAgent = packageName + "/" + info.versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

    if (stack == null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
            stack = new HurlStack();
        } else {
            // Prior to Gingerbread, HttpUrlConnection was unreliable.
            // See: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html
            stack = new HttpClientStack(AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(userAgent));
        }
    }

    Network network = new ManualProxyNetwork(new BasicNetwork(stack));

    RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue(new DiskBasedCache(cacheDir), network);
    queue.start();

    return queue;
}
```

A simple solution is just to copy this method to your application, and modify the user agent string to use your app name instead of the package name. It would be a simple 1 line change. 
Then just call your custom newRequestQueue method instead of the volley method.

Comment: i tested it, but it's not working and sent requests with default android user-agent like `Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; Nexus 7 Build/JWR66Y)` , did you check it before? thanks

Comment: i only want to change the `Dalvik/1.6.0` to my app name or other thing

Comment: Look closely and you'll see the string it's only used in the case the `stack` parameter passed to this method is null AND only in android version lower to 9 (almost never :s). Its a pity that `HurlStack` doesn't offer a way to adjust the user agent header (although you could do it by extending the `getHeaders` method in your `Request` implementation